# How can I click using ffi in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, node-ffi

I am creating a robot for Windows. To move the mouse, this is my code so far:

```
var ffi = require('ffi'),
    user32 = ffi.Library('user32', {
        'SetCursorPos': ['long', ['long', 'long']]
    });;


user32.SetCursorPos(100,100);
```

I need a function that using ffi (or any other way) will click to given coordinates like

```
click(100,100);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
var ffi = require('ffi'),
    user32 = ffi.Library('user32', {
        'SetCursorPos': ['long', ['long', 'long']],
        'mouse_event': ['void', ['int', 'int', 'int', 'int', 'int']]
    });;

MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 2;
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 4;

user32.SetCursorPos(3, 3);

user32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0);
user32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```